# Creating photoshop layer blend effects in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, mix-blend-mode, background-blend-mode

I need to provide this image with css. A layer must be placed on the image. I can't get exactly the same appearance. Is there a solution to this? It can also be an SVG filter.

Intended result: [image]

I've tried it, but I can't make it.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5W7Q.jpg");
  background-color: rgba(16, 24, 45, 0.8);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem much later. I'd better add it here. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57347582/10698741).

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5W7Q.jpg");
  background-color: rgba(16, 24, 45, 0.8);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  position: relative;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div::before {
  background-color: gray;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}

div::after {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-color: #98aeea;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the image on a pseudo-element (`::before`) under the `div` (`z-index: -1`), and use the `grayscale` filer to convert it to black & white.

Set the semi-transparent background color (`rgba(16, 24, 45, 0.8)`) on the `div`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(16, 24, 45, 0.8);
}

div::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5W7Q.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```