# How change hue of image with different colors with css filter to hue of blue

Tags: html, css, css-filters

I have image with different colors. In adobe photoshop my image filtered with smart filter which add hue, saturation, brightness to image. So I need to change all colors on image to hue of blue. But in css hue-rotate() function rotate all colors, but i need to set one color and change some saturation and brightness.This is source image: [image: source image]
I need to get this: [image: filtered image]
How i can set one hue color on image with css filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider `mix-blend-mode` property.

With pseudo elements and with background-image:

```css
.img {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMWO8.png");
  width: 1280px;
  height: 302px;
  position: relative;
}
.img::before, .img::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.img::before {
  background-color: gray;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}
.img::after {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="img"></div>
```

Or img tags.

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 302px;
}

.origin, .color-overlay--1, .color-overlay--2 {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.origin {
  z-index:1;
}

.color-overlay--1 {
  z-index:2;
  background-color:gray;
  mix-blend-mode:color;
}

.color-overlay--2 {
  z-index:3;
  mix-blend-mode:overlay;
  background-color:#98aeea;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMWO8.png" alt="" class="origin">
  <div class="color-overlay--1"></div>
  <div class="color-overlay--2"></div>
</div>
```

So you can turn it into any color you want.

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 302px;
}

.origin, .color-overlay--1, .color-overlay--2 {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.origin {
  z-index:1;
}

.color-overlay--1 {
  z-index:2;
  background-color:gray;
  mix-blend-mode:color;
}

.color-overlay--2 {
  z-index:3;
  mix-blend-mode:overlay;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMWO8.png" alt="" class="origin">
  <div class="color-overlay--1"></div>
  <div class="color-overlay--2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, i have one more question. How i can do that with transparent image? I don't want to see blue background on transparent area

Comment: @VsevolodFedorov you can give them all opacity?

Answer (score 5):

You can combine a sepia filter with hue-rotate to approximate it:

```css
img {
 max-width:100%;
 filter:sepia(1) hue-rotate(149deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMWO8.png">
```

Comment: oh, its good idea, but how i can calculate properties to get same result as in photoshop?

Comment: @VsevolodFedorov here it become tricky :) you need to dig into the complex calculation in order to find the formula or you do it with trivial and error until you get the needed result