# Change the color of a SVG icon similar to grayscale but to shades of blue with CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have a list of SVG icons that has colors in them which I use to display like below

[image: SVG Color List]

**I want to be able to re-use these SVG elsewhere in my webapp but change the color of the icons so that instead of showing color it only shows a certain shade of color. (Blue)**

[image: What I want]

**Is there a way to change this to blue similar to grayscale via CSS? (I'd rather not upload a separate SVG to do this)**

The closest I got was something from following this [How change hue of image with different colors with css filter to hue of blue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347508/how-change-hue-of-image-with-different-colors-with-css-filter-to-hue-of-blue)

But **I don’t want the square background** right behind the icon. (I just want the SVG to change color)

```css
.background {
  padding: 16px;
  background: rgb(199, 229, 242);
}

.donut {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
}


.donut::before, .donut::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.donut::before {
  background-color: gray;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}
.donut::after {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="donut">
    <svg  fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M23.778 4.36A14 14 0 0016 2v5a9 9 0 11-9 9H2A14 14 0 1023.778 4.36z" fill="#E1BD16"/>
      <path d="M6.1 6.1A14 14 0 002 16h5a9 9 0 019-9V2a14 14 0 00-9.9 4.1z" fill="#F85F4E"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can add a position absolute SVG with a fill of the color that you want. Then using `mix-blend-mode: overlay;` and `filter: grayscale(1);` you can get the shade of color that you want

```css
.background {
  padding: 16px;
  background: rgb(199, 229, 242);
}

.donut {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  z-index: 1;
}

.donut-background {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.donut-background * {
  fill: #2C93BF;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <svg class="donut-background" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M23.778 4.36A14 14 0 0016 2v5a9 9 0 11-9 9H2A14 14 0 1023.778 4.36z" fill="#E1BD16"/>
      <path d="M6.1 6.1A14 14 0 002 16h5a9 9 0 019-9V2a14 14 0 00-9.9 4.1z" fill="#F85F4E"/>
    </svg>
    
    
    <svg class="donut" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M23.778 4.36A14 14 0 0016 2v5a9 9 0 11-9 9H2A14 14 0 1023.778 4.36z" fill="#E1BD16"/>
      <path d="M6.1 6.1A14 14 0 002 16h5a9 9 0 019-9V2a14 14 0 00-9.9 4.1z" fill="#F85F4E"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also apply a css **filter** directly on your donut icon like so:

```
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(75%);
```

**Simple color shift example**

```css
.background {
  padding: 16px;
  background: rgb(199, 229, 242);
}

.icon-use {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.filter-blue-hover:hover,
.filter-blue {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(75%);
}
```

```html
<svg class="donut" style="display:none" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <symbol id="icon">
      <path d="M23.778 4.36A14 14 0 0016 2v5a9 9 0 11-9 9H2A14 14 0 1023.778 4.36z" fill="#E1BD16" />
      <path d="M6.1 6.1A14 14 0 002 16h5a9 9 0 019-9V2a14 14 0 00-9.9 4.1z" fill="#F85F4E" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
<div class="background">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="icon-use filter-blue">
    <use href="#icon" />
  </svg>
</div>
<p>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="icon-use filter-blue-hover">
    <use href="#icon" />
  </svg> Filter on hover - no background color needed.
</p>
```

**Edit: normalized colorizing**
This example avoids undesired colors caused by relative hue shifts.
We first tint everything to a sepia tone by `sepia(100%)`.
By this normalizing step, we can make sure all filtered colors will be in the desired hue range ("blueish" in this case).

```js
//toggleFilter
function toggleFilter() {
  let filterItems = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleFilter");
  filterItems.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.classList.toggle("filter-blue");
  });
}
```

```css
.icon-use {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10vw;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.filter-blue {
  transition: 0.3s filter ease-in-out;
  filter: invert(0%) sepia(100%) saturate(300%) hue-rotate(-180deg);
}

.filter-blue:hover {
  filter: invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(100%) hue-rotate(0deg);
}

.icon-wrp {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="btnFilter" onclick="toggleFilter()">Toggle Filter</button>

</p>

<svg class="donut" style="display:none" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <symbol id="slice">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="none" pathLength="99" />
    </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="icon-wrp">
  <!-- pie chart-->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="toggleFilter">
        <use href="#slice" stroke="#E1BD16" stroke-width="16" />
        <use href="#slice" stroke="#F85F4E" stroke-width="16" stroke-dasharray="33 100" />
        <use href="#slice" stroke="purple" stroke-width="16" stroke-dashoffset="-33" stroke-dasharray="33 100" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrp">
  <!-- pie chart-->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="toggleFilter " transform="scale(1.5)">
        <use href="#slice" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
        <use href="#slice" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="33 100" />
        <use href="#slice" stroke="orange" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="-33" stroke-dasharray="33 100" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrp">
  <!-- pie chart-->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="toggleFilter ">
        <use href="#slice" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="16" />
        <use href="#slice" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="16" stroke-dasharray="33 100" />
        <use href="#slice" stroke="magenta" stroke-width="16" stroke-dashoffset="-33" stroke-dasharray="33 100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

This approach is based on the popular svg coloring concept described here [(How to change the color of an svg element?).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element#answer-70127259)

**The main benefit:**
you don't need additional (background) elements to control the mix-blendmode color calculations.

**Drawbacks:**
you will have to tweak the different hue-shift properties to get the desired color result.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately sometimes the SVG would have a different color (i.e Purple + Yellow + Red) where doing hue-rotate + saturate cause the purple color to turn green but I do need everything to be a shade of blue regardless of color of the icons.

Comment: This might be a good answer for someone who might not have as many dynamic colors as I do though! Added an upvote for you (:

Comment: @Kenneth Truong - I see ... I've added a "normalized" colorizing method to my answer that might be closer to your needs: it will prevent the filtered color to end up in a unwanted color range (like green).

Answer (score 0):

Using filter with just the SVG's paths not the background to change color based on the original colors:

```css
.background {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.donut {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.donut svg:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="donut">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M23.778 4.36A14 14 0 0016 2v5a9 9 0 11-9 9H2A14 14 0 1023.778 4.36z" fill="#E1BD16"/>
      <path d="M6.1 6.1A14 14 0 002 16h5a9 9 0 019-9V2a14 14 0 00-9.9 4.1z" fill="#F85F4E"/>
    </svg>
  </div><br>
  Hover over image.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately I was looking for each path to have a different shade of blue based on the current colors. This causes every shape to be blue without having different shades.